# How to pass arguments to a Java process from within a shell script

Tags: shell, quoting

This may be a duplicate but the initial questions I have found the answer did not resolve the issue.

Yet another re-write of the question.

I have this Java application:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("DEBUG: arguments passed to the main - " + Arrays.toString(args));
    System.exit(new TaskRunner().run(args));
}
```

If I call the code directly with two arguments:

> `$ nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -cp /opt/fxudply/fxcal-client-jar/current/lib:/opt/fxudply/fxcal-client-jar/current/lib/*:/opt/fxudply/fxcal-config/current/wib-config:/opt/fxudply/fxcal-config/current/wib-config/* wib.runner.TaskRunner -taskExtRef "QUOTES_UPLOAD IPV - EOD Rates Input - Commodities Volatilities" > /opt/sw/calypso/logs/taskrunner/log.direct.log 2>&1`

it prints

> `[TaskRunner] DEBUG: : arguments passed to the main - [-taskExtRef, QUOTES_UPLOAD IPV - EOD Rates Input - Commodities Volatilities]`

which is what I expect. 
But if I write this shell script (`startScheduledTask.sh`):

> `` NOW_DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'` ``
>
> `nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -cp some:classpath:values package.name.classname "$@"   > /opt/random/path/tplogs/classname/${aVariableLogName}.${NOW_DATE}.log 2>&1`

and run it as

> `$ ./startScheduledTask.sh -taskExtRef "QUOTES_UPLOAD IPV - EOD Rates Input -   Commodities Volatilities"  &`

I get this output:

> `[TaskRunner] DEBUG: : arguments passed to the main - [-taskExtRef, QUOTES_UPLOAD, IPV, -, EOD, Rates, Input, -, Commodities, Volatilities]`

(i.e., the second argument gets broken up into nine arguments,
because it contains eight spaces). 
Therefore I believe that the script is at fault.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify: how are you getting the lists of arguments that you show in the bottom half of your question, and what do you want to get?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Please review and let me know if this clears up the question.

Comment: The part you showed is correct, so the error is in one of the parts you didn't show. Probably in the way you invoke that script. Show us that part.

Comment: Here's some quick advice: Withholding relevant information is bad, because it makes it impossible for us to figure out what's going on.  Bombarding us with irrelevant information is bad, because it makes it too hard for us to *find* the relevant information.  I realize that distinguishing between relevant information and irrelevant information can be hard, especially for somebody who is just learning.  But please try harder.

Comment: I edited your question again.  Of course, if you believe that I have misrepresented your situation or left out something important or critical, put it back.  But do not make statements about “JCommander” without telling us what it is and what it has to do with your question.  … … … … … … …  Why do your debug messages say `DEBUG: : arguments` when your debug *code* says `DEBUG: arguments`?  … … … … … … … …  P.S. I updated my answer; please see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the shell parses a command line,
it removes quotes but remembers the text structure that they imply. 
(That is a gross oversimplification;
see [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) for more details.) 
For example, the command-line input

```
-blah apple -secondfruit "green banana" -some more
```

causes the shell to identify six words, or tokens:

1. `-blah`
2. `apple`
3. `-secondfruit`
4. `green banana`
5. `-some`
6. `more`

which will be stored in memory as

```
-blahⓧappleⓧ-secondfruitⓧgreen bananaⓧ-someⓧmoreⓧ
```

where `ⓧ` represents a null byte. 
This will then sometimes be displayed or reported as

```
-blah apple -secondfruit green banana -some more
```

so you might believe that the quotes are just being ignored,
and you have seven words, while, in fact, you have what you want.

> ### Note:
>
> In the above, `ⓧ` represents a null byte. 
>   What I'm describing here is *standard* shell argument-parsing processing. 
>   If you type
>
> ```
> ls -l fruit.sh "I came here for an argument" startScheduledTask.sh
> ```
>
> the `/bin/ls` program gets invoked with the string
>
> ```
> lsⓧ-lⓧfruit.shⓧI came here for an argumentⓧstartScheduledTask.shⓧ
> ```
>
> in memory, and this gets interpreted as
>
> - argv[0] = `ls`
> - argv[1] = `-l`
> - argv[2] = `fruit.sh`
> - argv[3] = `I came here for an argument`
> - argv[4] = `startScheduledTask.sh`
>
> This ***exact same process*** happens if you are
>
> 1. typing a `java` command directly into your primary, interactive shell,
> 2. executing a `java` command that is in a shell script, or
> 3. running a shell script by typing a command like `./startScheduledTask.sh`
>      directly into your primary, interactive shell,
>
> so *this is not the problem.* 
>   Any program that cannot handle having its arguments separated by null characters
>   **cannot work in Unix & Linux.**

## TL;DR

Your first command is correct.  `"$@"` gives you what you want;
it is the correct way for a shell script to pass its arguments
to a program that it calls.  If you add debug code to your program
to loop through its arguments, printing each one on a new line,
and/or in brackets (but not all on one line, separated only by spaces),
you will see that the `"$@"` is passing six arguments to the program.

---

### OK, even more:

- Your class path has asterisks (**`*`**s) in it?  Really? 
  I’m a little out of practice with Java, but that seems odd to me. 
  Please double-check that you’re doing that correctly for your system. 
  But, if it works correctly when you type the classpath with asterisks “directly”
  (i.e., directly into your main shell; your primary, interactive shell;
  your login shell), then that’s *probably* not the problem.

  But please humor me and put that string into quotes, anyway.
- Your problem is too complicated.  When you’re building an airplane,
  you don’t build the entire plane and then try to fly it. 
  And then, when it doesn’t fly, you don’t step back and ask,
  “What’s wrong with the plane?” 
  No, you test it in pieces.  You need to simplify.

  - Stop running it in the background.
  - Stop saying `nohup`.
  - Stop redirecting the output.
  - Don’t show your 42-character long shell prompt in your question.
  - Your question is *about* an argument with spaces in it,
    so don’t take that out,
    but it doesn’t have to be 60 characters long with eight spaces. 
    `green banana` is a *great* test value.
  - Try it with arguments to your program *not* beginning with **`-`** (dash).
  - Maybe even comment out the `new TaskRunner().run(args)` part
    of your program, leaving only the DEBUG and `System.exit(0);`.

  None of these *should* make a difference. 
  But they are distractions that make it hard to see what’s important. 
  If you can demonstrate the problem in a minimal test configuration,
  we can rule out all those other things as being related to the problem. 
  But, if the problem goes away when you remove the irrelevant things,
  then one of them was probably causing the problem.

  Also, please stop mixing fake/test data and real data
  (i.e., fruits and tasks) in the question.
- Please write this script (call it `fruity.sh`):

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

                  # classpath
  CP="/opt/fxudply/fxcal-client-jar/current/lib:/opt/fxudply/fxcal-client-jar/current/lib/*:/opt/fxudply/fxcal-config/current/wib-config:/opt/fxudply/fxcal-config/current/wib-config/*"
                  # package.name.classname
  PC=wib.runner.TaskRunner

  "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java  -cp "$CP"  "$PC"  "$@"
  ```

  and run

  ```
  ./fruity.sh taskExtRef "green banana"
  ```

  If the debug says

  ```
  …[taskExtRef, green banana]
  ```

  then the `"$@"` is working correctly,
  and the problem lies elsewhere in your script.  Try to find it. 
  Make one change at a time and see how the behavior changes. 
  If you can’t figure it out, we may be able to help you,
  but only if you show us the part of the script that’s *causing* the problem.

  But if the debug says

  ```
  …[taskExtRef, green, banana]
  ```

  then let us know.

Comment: thank you, I will have to do a new build and deploy with some proper debugging on Monday. I'm actually heading home now but at least I'm not as crazy as what I thought I am.

Comment: After testing the solution its not passing the arguments correctly from the script: The java code prints out the following arguments as passed: After testing the solution its not passing the arguments correctly from the script: The java code prints out the following arguments as passed: [TaskRunner] DEBUG: : arguments passed to the main - [-taskExtRef, QUOTES_UPLOAD, IPV, -, EOD, Rates, Input, -, Commodities, Volatilities]
This was printed using: System.out.println("DEBUG: arguments passed to the main - " + Arrays.toString(args));

Comment: The output is as expected with the fruity script.